# how to set src property to out of project url?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Im working on an ionic project. I want to insert a variable that contains the Url of an image into image tag. ()

```
<div *ngFor="let item of imagearr">
<img src=item.image.URL>
```

I tried this but it didnot read the content of URL.
I also tried [src] instead of src, didnt help neither.
TNX ur help!

Comment: You need to use quotes. `<img [src]="item.image.url" />`

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap it inside a banana box like this,
 [src] ="item.image.URL"

Comment: u know that item.image.URL is string property of object item right?

Comment: @riki, It should be inside the quotes

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following approach ,

```
<img src={{item.image.URL}}>
```

Try out the following approach .

Answer (score 0):

As others have said you could use this approach:

```
<img [src]="item.image.url" />
```

The square brackets is how Angular knows to evaluate the attribute value as an Angular expression instead of as a string literal.

Alternatively, you could do something like this:

```
<img src="{{item.image.url}}" />
```

In this syntax the double curly brackets is what tells Angular to process the contents as an expression instead of a literal.

Comment: could be that the problem is because the url is from cloud? i mean- when my url was in the project everything was fine but now- my url is actually from image stored in bucket in the cloud. and nothing works.

Comment: I assumed the problem was that the `img src` property was not being set.  If it is being set; then there could be other issues at play.  Any web app or mobile app should be able to load an image from a cloud, assuming that image is publicly available.